# how can i assign image name to string variable

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I am new to iPhone. What i need is i have to assign image name (eg.parrot.jpg) to NSString value.i need to display image in imageview using this string variable.

apporxmatly `imageview.image = NSStringvarible;`  where NSStringVArible is image name.

How can i done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *imageName = @"parrot.jpg";

UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
youreImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"parrot.jpg"];
```

Comment: what i need is imageview.image = NSstringVariable; where string variable is parrot.jpg how can i done this

Comment: Instead of jumping in to try and get this working I would recommend that you learn the basics of Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:NSStringvarible];
```

as imageview.image needs image and not simple string... So you line will give you warning and will terminate the application
Use the above line will help you solve the problem...

hAPPY iCODING...